# How do you calculate multiclass microaverage precision and recall?

Tags: precision-recall, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix that is 4 class.

```
                                 Ground Truth
                  Class A    Class B    Class C     Class D
        Class A      a          b          c           d
Pred    Class B      e          f          g           h
        Class C      i          j          k           l
        Class D      m          n          o           p
```

For macro-average precision and recall is easy: simply calculate the precision of each class and average them. For example,
Precision of class A = a / (a + b + c + d)

What about micro-average precision and recall?